# Typing date into a cell returns nonsense date in the year 7436

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel is doing something funky.

I'm trying to type dates.
When I type `02022015` into a cell, it change the number to `2/1/7436`.

Any ideas why it's doing this? Ghost? Operator error? Not enough coffee?

Comment: If you highlight the cell and go to Properties under formatting you can change the cell to your desired format

Answer (score 3):

So, you've already formatted the cell as a date. When you enter the date as you've typed it, Excel sees it as a number, `2,022,015`. The source of the problem is that Excel actually stores dates as numbers, specifically as the number of days since January 1, 1900. What you've entered is interpreted by Excel as the date 2,022,015 days after January 1, 1900, which is `2/1/7436`.

To get around this, you need to enter your date in a way that Excel won't confuse for a number. Try an accepted date format, like `mm-dd-yyyy` or `m/d/yyyy`. That is, type this instead:

```
02-02-2015
```

or

```
2/2/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't type a date as a long integer because Excel can't understand that it is a date.

Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so they can be used in calculations.

By default, January 1, 1900 is *1*, and for example January 1, 2015 is 42005 because it is 42,005 days after January 1, 1900.

In consecuence 020202015 will be converted to date rendering `2/1/7436`.

Use a separator character as **/** or **-**.

However, if you have the data in that format, for example in cell `A1`then this formula can help you:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/0000")+0
```